# Recommended Blogs / Sites for AD&D

Tags: adnd-1e

Coming back to RPGs after a decade or two out, it occurs to me that the internet is probably littered with people writing interesting and amusing things on the subjects.

Can anyone recommend any decent blogs or sites covered AD&D (either primarily or with a large AD&D content)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flagship blog for old-school rules-light D&D is IMO [Grognardia](http://grognardia.blogspot.com/). He emphasizes Basic and Original D&D over AD&D due to his preference for (spontaneous) "rulings over rules" but he does cover AD&D 1st Edition (and to some extent 2nd) and other games of the era.

A great source of classes, characters, and other playable material is [Joesky the Dungeon Brawler](http://joeskythedungeonbrawler.wordpress.com/).

[Sickly Purple Death Ray](http://sicklypurpledeathray.blogspot.com/) posts good maps and game art.

[Greyhawk Grognard](http://greyhawkgrognard.blogspot.com/) has a clone of AD&D 1e called Adventures Dark & Deep.

IMO if you are getting back into RPGs after 10-20 years, the biggest change is the movement away from T$R and other commercial publishers, toward community-supported grass-roots material. The "Old School Renaissance" folks who post freely downloadable clones and re-interpretations of classic games are perhaps the best exemplars.

Answer (score 6):

If you want gamers instead of bloggers, sprain your mousefinger hurrying to **DragonsFoot**:

http://www.dragonsfoot.org

- Forums:
  http://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/
- Downloads for 1e:
  http://www.dragonsfoot.org/fe/
- Downloads for 2e:
  http://www.dragonsfoot.org/se/

otoh if you're into collecting old/original D&D (2e & earlier), there's a specialty site for advice on buying & selling, **The Acaeum**:

- http://www.acaeum.com/
- Forums: http://www.acaeum.com/forum/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Currently the number of blogs, twitter posters and websites devoted to just D&D stagger the imagination.  And not just 4e.  You can find content and comments on every edition and every campaign published.  You can even find sites that list other peoples campaigns. I would say half the fun is finding these sites and exploring them.  Your favorite search engine will give you page after page of sites, some will be better than others.

I guess the short answer is what are you looking for.  General info, how-to, ideas or something else?  That will direct your searches.

I have over 60 book marked links that I have limited myself to.  They range from discussions to rules interpretations (crunchy bits).

I would start with the following sites as they tend to have a slightly broader view than just D&D.

[Critical Hits](http://critical-hits.com/) - All kinds of things to read and think about

[Roleplaying Tips](http://www.roleplayingtips.com/) - Fantastic resource of lists, content, ideas and just plan good stuff

[Kobold Quarterly](http://www.koboldquarterly.com/) - good source of information and ideas.

[Newbie DM](http://newbiedm.com/) - Looking through the eyes of a DM who hasn't been DM'ing very long and is willing to share those trials with the world.

[Robin D Laws](http://robin-d-laws.livejournal.com/) - Author and DM who is the authority on many things RPG

[Campaign Mastery](http://www.campaignmastery.com/blog/) - ideas on how to run a better game

[Osidian Portal](http://www.obsidianportal.com/) - Other peoples campaigns A great resource

I do not know any of these people (I wish I did), but have found them very helpful and insightful in many ways.  Most of these sites have links that will take you to other sights that they follow.

Comment: Which of these are specifically good for AD&D? I like several of these, but most of the good stuff from several of them is dnd-4e specific.

Answer (score 1):

[**RPG Geek**](http://www.rpggeek.com) has forums for every game in the database. Including some slow but steady AD&D 1E traffic.

[RPG Pundit's **The RPG Site**](http://www.therpgsite.com/) isn't safe for work, but it is candid and has a love of old-school. It can be rather toxic, tho, as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about first edition AD&D (which is what the [adnd] tag means, if you mean D&D in general you should retag as [dungeons-and-dragons]) There is a movement called the "[Old School Renaissance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/what-defines-the-old-school-renaissance)," or OSR, where people are playing old editions like AD&D 1e and/or "[retro-clones](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/overview-of-dd-retro-clones)" that are variations on those old rules. The communities around the OSR and the 1e retro-clones like OSRIC, [Castles & Crusades](http://trolldens.blogspot.com), and Swords & Wizardry Core will have more than you can ever read.